# Merging duplicate contact entries from multiple sources

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I have multiple copies of the same contacts on my phone, from the Google account associated, and phone contacts etc.

Eg., for a single contact I might have:

- 2 copies on the phone
- 1 copy on my Google account (synced)
- another copy in some other location

This happened on my HTC Wildfire a year ago and now I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Is there a way I can merge all related contacts and delete the other extra copies? It'd be helpful if I could do this from my PC.

Comment: Just for clarification: Are all copies sync'd to your GMail account? Or are some just stored differently (e.g. on SIM or phone storage)?

Answer (score 2):

Remember: when creating a contact, you can decide where to store it. Usually, there are at least 3 choices: Google, SIM, phone.

If I read your question correctly, it looks like you have a copy in each of these places. In this case, [Tirath's suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52004/16575) doesn't work, as GMail will only see what's sync'd there (and phone + SIM don't get sync'd). You then might want to take a look at apps like [Contact Remover](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Contact-Remover/com.octabode.dcfd) (to ease deletion of the duplicates), or [Contact Remover Plus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/contact-remover-plus/com.holyhog.dcfdpro) which also offers to merge or move them.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android.merger&hl=en) can link contacts from different accounts together.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry @Community Bot. I had exactly the problem described above, I tried 6 applications and one of them was Merge +, was the only one able to link accounts together, the other 5 apps removed duplicate informations, but did not link them together.
I tried
- Cleaner - Doppelte Kontakte zusammenfügen
- Kontakte zusammenführen
- Doppelte Kontaktverschmelzung
- Duplicate Contacts Finder - Contact Optimizer Pro
- Contacts Optimizer
- Contacts Sync Fix
- Doppelte Kontakte Remover